# Gradle flavors with duplicate names but different dimension

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-flavordimension

Is it possible to have the following setup:

```
flavorDimension "production", "staging"

productFlavors {
    staging {
        dimension "staging"
        ...
    }

    production {
        dimension "production"
        ...
    }

    flavorOne {
        dimension "staging"
        ...
    }

    flavorOne {
        dimension "production"
        ...
    }

}
```

flavorOne exists two times and contains different settings but also with different dimensions.

What I need is a flavor flavorOne with production and staging and also res files for flavorOneStaging and flavorOneProduction.
If I am doing it like this, I only see flavorOneStagingDebug and flavorOneStagingRelease (release and debug are my buildTypes) but nor flavorOneProduction..

Do I have to create a flavor for every combination?
Staging and production contains data that never changes except res files and flavorOne is just one of N. I don't want to create N*2 flavors to have every flavor in production and staging?
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is:

```
flavorDimension "environment", "flavorType"

productFlavors {
    staging {
        dimension "environment"
        ...
    }

    production {
        dimension "environment"
        ...
    }

    flavorOne {
        dimension "flavorType"
        ...
    }

    flavorTwo {
        dimension "flavorType"
        ...
    }

}
```

Assuming your build types are release and debug, this will produce:

```
staging-flavorone-release.apk
staging-flavorone-debug.apk
staging-flavortwo-release.apk
staging-flavortwo-debug.apk
release-flavorone-release.apk
release-flavorone-debug.apk
release-flavortwo-release.apk
release-flavortwo-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no default way to do this - I had the same problem once and solved it like this:

applicationVariants.all { variant ->

```
    def variantName = variant.name
    if (variantName == "flavorOneProduction") {
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "FOO",'"BAR"'
    } else if (variantName == "flavorOneStaging") {
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "FOO",'"BAR2"'
    } else if (variantName == "flavorTwoProduction") {
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "FOO",'"BAR3"'
    } else if (variantName == "flavorTwoStaging") {
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "FOO",'"BAR4"'
    } 
}
```

I think you get the gist

Answer (score 0):

Please read: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants

There you should see that you should to this the other way round: have production and staging applied as flavors and maybe then apply dimensions on them (if its still needed).

Comment: I read it already but it does not explain what I need. Right now I have 4 flavors. Flavor1Staging, Flavor1Production, Flavor2Staging and Flavor2Production. If I add one more flavors I have to create always 2. staging and production have different settings but also does Flavor1 and Flavor2. For example: staging has a flag ads=false, production ads=true and Flavor1 has a value url=xyz and Flavor2 has url=yzx. A dimension can not have default values right?

Comment: What I need is something like: Flavor1 extends Staging

Comment: I don't think that this is possible as this multiplies always. Maybe it would be an option for you to disable the flavors you do not want on the gradle buildgraph.

Comment: I will always need all flavors - its a whitelabel solution where, if I build, I will need all flavors. but ok, I think I have to create many flavors then. Thanks